# Increase row limit of Apache Superset

Tags: apache-superset

I tried increasing the row limit of Apache Superset from 50000 to 500000 in the config.py file. But even after changing the limit, I was limited to see only 100000 rows using the table chart in Apache Superset.

Is there any way to increase the row limit to more than 100000 and display more than 100000 rows in table chart ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Locate & open the `superset_config.py` file, add OR modify the configuration parameter:

`SQL_MAX_ROW = your_desired_maximum_row_limit`